# Google calendar event API date filter is not working

Tags: java, api, rest, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar API to fetch the event lists. What I am doing over here is I am adding filter to get event of specific date, so for that I have used timeMin and timeMax keys. But this filter is not working at all. It is giving me results of other dates as well. Can someone please help me with what am I doing wrong?

Here is my request URL.

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/EMAIL/events?key=KEY&timeMin=2021-07-15T00:00:00.000Z&timeMax=2021-07-17T00:00:00.000Z&timeZone=Asia/Calcutta

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

### The `timeMin` and `timeMax` parameters are confusing and do not correspond to the `Date` options `from...to` of the UI search

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list):

> timeMax:  Upper bound (exclusive) for an event's **start time** to filter by.

> timeMin:  Lower bound (exclusive) for an event's **end time** to filter by.

In other words, defining

`timeMin=2021-07-15T00:00:00.000Z&timeMax=2021-07-17T00:00:00.000Z`

will return you all events that started before `2021-07-17T00:00:00.000Z` and end after `2021-07-17T00:00:00.000Z`.

You need to modify the query and look for event on the date indirectly by e.g. looking for events that started before `2021-07-17T23:59:59.999Z` and ended after `2021-07-17T00:00:00.000Z`.

Thereby, make sure to set `singleEvents` to `true` to exlucde event series (recurring events).

Once you have a list of candidates, you might still need to query for the `start` and `end` properties of the [event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource) and filter out the spare results.

Comment: I am afraid about started before and end after things. It seems like a calendar API searches for UTC times only, so after passing converted values I am able to get records.